# Difference between center and centercontinuous alignment in ClosedXML?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, openxml, closedxml, format-string

I am working on ClosedXML for Export an Excel, and just find a property for alignment **Center and CenterContinuous**.

```
worksheet.Column(9).Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
```

And

```
worksheet.Column(9).Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.CenterContinuous;
```

I have tried both, but the results remain same, anybody know what the exact difference?

Comment: Please play fair and mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CenterContinuous will center text along cells with same style.

Comment: Your answer is not clear at all. E.g. I have three cells: a, b, c. a - has red color and blue background color, b - has blue background color and red color, c - has red color and red background color. a - aligned left, b - aligned right. Will c be aligned left or right? It has the same style with both a and b.